# React/TSX file not executing in scripting.executeScript() method - Chrome Extension MV3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension using React, TypeScript, and Webpack.

In **background.js**, I'm querying the tabs using `chrome.tabs.query` and checking if the urls include "example" since I'm using `example.com` for testing. Then, I use `chrome.scripting.executeScript` to inject a React TSX component onto the DOM, but it doesn't work. Both the service worker and example.com consoles are free of errors.

When I use vanilla JS in **ExampleScript.js**, it works fine. I injecte a red div element onto the webpage and got an alert to pop up. It's only when I try to use React that it breaks.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Test",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage", 
    "tabs", 
    "scripting",
    "webRequest"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [<all_urls>],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**webpack.common.config**

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    popup: path.resolve('src/popup/popup.tsx'),
    options: path.resolve('src/options/options.tsx'),
    background: path.resolve('src/background/background.ts'),
    contentScript: path.resolve('src/contentScript/contentScript.tsx'),
    ExampleScript: path.resolve('src/components/ExampleScript/ExampleScript.tsx')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false,
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.resolve('src/static'),
          to: path.resolve('dist'),
        }
      ]
    }),
    ...getHtmlPlugins([
      'popup',
      'options'
    ]),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/dist',
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks(chunk) {
        return chunk.name !== 'ExampleScript' 
      },
    },
  }
}

function getHtmlPlugins(chunks) {
  return chunks.map(chunk => new HtmlPlugin({
    title: 'Test Extension',
    filename: `${chunk}.html`,
    chunks: [chunk],
  }))
}
```

**background.ts**

```
let queryOptions = {
    currentWindow: true,
};
    
chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions).then(tabs => {
    tabs.forEach((tab) => {
        if (tab.url.includes('example')) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                {
                    target: {
                        tabId: tab.id,  
                    },
                    files: ['ExampleScript.js'] 
                }
            );     
        }
    })
})
```

**ExampleScript.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import './ExampleScript.css';

alert('EXAMPLE SCRIPT');

const ExampleScript = () => {
  console.log('Example Script working')
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(root);
ReactDOM.render(<ExampleScript/>, root);
```

Comment: Check the generated file and see if it has react runtime inside. If not, configure webpack accordingly. BTW, you can also inject the UI into an iframe for more flexibility, control, and safety ([example](https://itnext.io/create-chrome-extension-with-reactjs-using-inject-page-strategy-137650de1f39)).

Comment: How do I check if a runtime exists and how would I reconfigure webpack? I'm looking in the generated js (/dist/ExampleScript.js) and can see that react and react-dom are being imported yet I can't console.log(React.version)

Comment: The js fle won't have imports, it should have actual js code of react runtime.

Comment: Apologies, I was referring to webpack harmony imports like `var react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! react */ "./node_modules/react/index.js");`. 

Still, I am completely lost. You mean something like this? `react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createElement("h1", null, "HELLO WORLD...in JSX"), root);`

Comment: I don't know React/webpack so I guess you need to make this entry point self-executable because currently it seems to only register itself via `__webpack_require__` but it doesn't run. Maybe you need to specify a different library target for webpack. P.S. I think the iframe approach is better though.

Comment: Just got it to work. Apparently the chunk splitting thing was messing everything up so I deleted the whole `optimization` section. Thanks for the help, also I'll be sure to use iframe in my components. Thanks for the help